# share - send via email in Dolphin does not work

Tags: arch-linux, email, thunderbird, plasma, dolphin

I'm using `KDE Plasma` with `Mozilla Thunderbird` as my default email client and I realized that when I right click a file in `Dolphin` and select `Share` - `Send via email`, I get an error popup titled  `Error - KIOExec` and it reads:

```
File not found: mailto:?attachement=file:///path/to/my/file.pdf
```

I did set Thunderbird as the default email client ion the `system settings` - how do I fix that?

My versions are:

```
Dolphin: 19.12.3
KDE Plasma: 5.18.3
Thunderbird: 68.5.0
```

Comment: Dolphin, KDE and Thunderbird versions? (works for me with Dolphin 19.04.3 in KDE 5.62 and TB 68.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Since Plasma 5, for some Kde version, you have to manually put a file in .local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ in waiting fix

file example: https://store.kde.org/p/998442/startdownload?file_id=1460731794&file_name=122832-thunderbird_attachment.desktop.zip&file_type=application/zip&file_size=905

Unzip in folder